# Can I use git command in delivery pipeline if git is installed in different path on jenkins agent than on master

Tags: git, jenkins, groovy, gerrit, delivery-pipeline

I have the following scenario.

I tried a simple pipeline job that clones my remote repo. It works fine when i set it to execute on master.

```
node {
   //stage 'Checkout'
     git([url: 'ssh://someusername@gerrit.mycompany.domain:29418/bla/bla.git', branch: 'mybranch'])
}
```

It uses the default git installation to run the command. I have configured git on a different pat for slave in jenkins configuration. 
when i try to run the same pipeline on a slave, it fails because it always tries to go the default git installation.

```
node ('myagent1'){
   //stage 'Checkout'
     git([url: 'ssh://someusername@gerrit.mycompany.domain:29418/bla/bla.git', branch: 'mybranch'])
}
```

The error is obvious:

```
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Error performing command: /jenkins-master-some-path/bin/git init /home/user/workspace/pipeline
```

`/jenkins-master-some-path/bin/git` is correct for master.

For normal jobs, we can choose one installation but can someone tell me  if there is a way to use different git installation for pipeline on a slave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution, that will work with all the tools, is to configure specific tools installations path for your specific agent node.

Go to :

```
Jenkins > Manage Nodes > myagent1 > nodes properties > tools
```

... and then select the tool that cannot be found on your agent (e.g. Git executable) and just fill there your executable path.

Comment: That could also work. I did not try but I agree to this solution theoratically.

Answer (score 1):

Ohhh
I found a way.
Instead of using git command, i used this "checkout" module.
From pipeline job configuration, if you click on "pipeline Syntax", it takes you to another page. There you can generate groovy just by using the GUI.