# There's no such executable D:\Git\bin\git.exe in PATH: /usr/local/sbin, /usr/local/bin, /usr/sbin, /usr/bin, /root/bin

Tags: jenkins, github

I am unable to find a clear path to execute the git operation in the Jenkins?

Comment: It would be helpful to provide some background details. Ex.: You are running on a cloud CI/CD product, and it has xyz configuration.

Answer (score 2):

That would be typical of a Jenkins agent on Linux, trying to access to a [Git plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/git/) whose PATH was set to a Windows one.

Make sure, as [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59273829/git-path-different-on-jenkins-agent-and-master#comment117624394_59273829), to specify the git location under the `tools` section for Linux agent, in the Jenkins node section.
Non-pipeline approach: "[Define the build tool only at Client master level](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/209591628-How-to-manage-build-tools-on-Client-masters-#3definethebuildtoolonlyatclientmasterlevel)".

Answer (score -1):

Installing `git` and restarting the Jenkins service worked for me:

```
yum install git
systemctl restart jenkins
```